# Can't add image in Asset catalog after updating to Xcode 11 GM Seed

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently I updated my xcode 11 beta version to `Xcode 11 GM Seed` and now, My Asset catalog kind of doesn't work. I'm getting errors on any photos I had in my asset,

```
2019-09-11 14:15:16.159 ibtoold[3321:122488] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
    TMPDIR = "/var/folders/js/9yy54t2145v7z3c8c240cbl00000gn/T/C2ABF262-A505-4044-A56B-899235F2E016";
}
2019-09-11 14:15:16.493 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3325:122673] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/sinamnouri/OneDrive/Documents/iOS/ProTech-iOS/ProTech-iOS/Assets.xcassets/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.imageset/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.png
2019-09-11 14:15:16.509 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3325:122673] CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for file:///Users/sinamnouri/OneDrive/Documents/iOS/ProTech-iOS/ProTech-iOS/Assets.xcassets/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.imageset/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.png
2019-09-11 14:15:16.517 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3325:122673] CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for file:///Users/sinamnouri/OneDrive/Documents/iOS/ProTech-iOS/ProTech-iOS/Assets.xcassets/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.imageset/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.png
2019-09-11 14:15:16.535 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[3325:122676] CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for file:///Users/sinamnouri/OneDrive/Documents/iOS/ProTech-iOS/ProTech-iOS/Assets.xcassets/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.imageset/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-02%20at%2015.41.29.png
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
: error: Distill failed for unknown reasons.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/sinamnouri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProTech-iOS-btktchaxrlqoowffdmaxojqvzury/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProTech-iOS.app/Assets.car
/Users/sinamnouri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProTech-iOS-btktchaxrlqoowffdmaxojqvzury/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProTech-iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProTech-iOS.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
```

Right now, I only have one single image in my asset and I get this error when I build the project.

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods?

Comment: @José yes I do.

Answer (score 4):

Had similar problems after updating to Xcode 11 GM.

I fixed my problem by doing the following:

1. Go to Build Phases
2. Expand `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`
3. Look for "Output files" and **remove** `"${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Assets.car"`

The project should now build. This entry will be re-added every time that you do a `pod update`.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, but after update the Catalina to the latest version fix my problem, because Xcode 11 downloaded additional tools after the OS update

Comment: Catalina will be available in October!